# MyBatis foreach with reference to enclosing object

Tags: java, foreach, mybatis

I have a Java object with a property which is a collection.
I'm using this collection in a MyBatis foreach loop.
In this loop I want to use a property of the parent object:

```
<foreach collection="collectionProperty" item="itemInCollection" open = "("separator=", " close=")">
     #{parentProperty} #{itemInCollection.itemValue}
</foreach>
```

Unfortunately this does not work since the scope of the foreach loop is the item in the collection.
Since the item does not have the property 'parentProperty' this results in an error.
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What error? You should be able to access parent object's property in `<foreach>`. Try creating a small repro project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues). If the issue reproduces, share it on your GitHub repo and I'll take a look when I have time.